# How can i add dynamic form field inside dynamic form field in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have created Dynamic add/delete form element using angular.

my expectation admin can add question first and admin can add options for that particular question question.

here i have added my code "ADD QUESTION" is working properly but once question added we need to create options for that particular question "ADD OPTIONS" not working properly

i have added both "ADD QUESTION" and "ADD OPTIONS" but when you add 2 or 3 question and remove its not working properly

for example i have added one question and 4 options for that qustion .after that if i click "ADD QUESTION" button question form is coming with 4 options field, here it should come only one option form field .its repeating the first question options

help me out to move forward

```js
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = {
   name: '',
    email: '',
    questions: [
      {
        id: 'choice1'
      }
    ],
 questionoption: [
      {
        id: 'option1'
      }
    ]
  };

  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.data.questions.length + 1;
    $scope.data.questions.push({
      'id': 'choice' + newItemNo
    });
  };
 
  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.data.questions.length - 1;
    $scope.data.questions.splice(lastItem);
  };
  
  $scope.OnSave = function() {
    console.log($scope.data);
  };

  
   $scope.addNewoptions = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.data.questionoption.length + 1;
    $scope.data.questionoption.push({
      'id': 'option' + newItemNo
    });
  };

  $scope.removeOption = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.data.questionoption.length - 1;
    $scope.data.questionoption.splice(lastItem);
  };
  
  
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  background: #FCFCFC;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
}
.fields {
  background: #FCFCFC;
  padding: 18px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.addfields {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#choicesDisplay {
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgb(227, 250, 227);
  border: 1px solid rgb(171, 239, 171);
  color: rgb(9, 56, 9);
}

.remove {
  background: #C76868;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 21px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 9px;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 100%;
}

input[type="text"],
select {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add question</button>
  <br>
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">name</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.name" name="" placeholder="Add name">
  <br>
  <br>
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">email</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.email" name="" placeholder="Add emalil">
  <br>
  <br>
  <fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in data.questions">
<button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewoptions()">Add options</button><br>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Add Question</label>

    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Add Question">
    <br>
    <br>


    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Question order</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.order" name="" placeholder="Add Question order">


    <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button><br><br>
     <div class="fields" data-ng-repeat="option in data.questionoption">
          
      <br>
   <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Add options</label>

   <input type="text" ng-model="option.options" name="" placeholder="Add options">
   <br>
   <br>


   <label class="control-label col-sm-2">options order</label>
   <input type="text" ng-model="option.order" name="" placeholder="Add Question order">


   <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeOption()">-</button> 
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <br>
  <br>


  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="OnSave()">Submit</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div id="choicesDisplay">
    {{ data.questions }}
  </div>
</div>
```

IF admin added one question(my expecttion result):

```
{

    "name": "test",
    "email": "as@gmail.com",
    "questions": [{
        "question": "Which of the following is the most important characteristic for a supervisor?",
        "questionorder": "1",
        "options": [{
                "val": "Approachable",
                "key": "options1"
            },
            {
                "val": "Qualified",
                "key": "options3"
            },
            {
                "val": "Honest",
                "key": "options2"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/74qd60d2/9/)

Comment: It is adding options too.Can you be more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer this fiddle I have corrected your code [working](http://jsfiddle.net/74qd60d2/16/)

Html code

```
    <div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add question</button>
  <br>
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">name</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.name" name="" placeholder="Add name">
  <br>
  <br>
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">email</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.email" name="" placeholder="Add emalil">
  <br>
  <br>
  <fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in data.questions" ng-init="Index = $index">
<button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewoptions(Index)">Add options</button><br>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Add Question</label>

    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Add Question">
    <br>
    <br>


    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Question order</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.order" name="" placeholder="Add Question order">


    <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button><br><br>
     <div class="fields" data-ng-repeat="option in choice.options">

      <br>
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Add options</label>

            <input type="text" ng-model="option.option" name="" placeholder="Add options">
            <br>
            <br>


            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">options order</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="option.order" name="" placeholder="Add Question order">


            <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeOption(Index)">-</button> 
          </div>
  </fieldset>
  <br>
  <br>


  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="OnSave()">Submit</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div id="choicesDisplay">
 <!--    {{ data.questions }} -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
    var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    questions: [
      {
        id: 'choice1',
        options : [{
            optid:'option1'
        }]
      }]
  };

  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.data.questions.length + 1;
    $scope.data.questions.push({
      'id': 'choice' + newItemNo,
      'options' : []
    });
  };

  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.data.questions.length - 1;
    $scope.data.questions.splice(lastItem);
  };

  $scope.OnSave = function() {
    console.log($scope.data);
  };


  $scope.addNewoptions = function(quest) {
        var newItemNo = $scope.data.questions[quest].options.length + 1;
        $scope.data.questions[quest].options.push({
          'optid': 'option' + newItemNo
        });
  };

  $scope.removeOption = function(quest) {
    var lastItem = $scope.data.questions[quest].options.length - 1;
        $scope.data.questions[quest].options.splice(lastItem);

  };

});
```